# How can I create wrapper for the types in the simple_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I want to create a wrapper for my app, but html for different types should be different. So, I can write just

```
= simple_for_for @task, wrapper: :mine_special do |f|
  = f.input :first_attr, type: :sring
  = f.input :second_attr, type: :boolean
```

so, my initializer will contain definitions for both `string` & `boolean` types:

```
config.wrappers :mine_special, types: [:boolean] do |b|
  # configs here for check box
end

config.wrappers :mine_special, types: [:string] do |b|
  # configs here for text field
end
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**In short**

The best solution I can think of is just naming your wrappers differently:

```
config.wrappers :mine_special_boolean
config.wrappers :mine_special_string
```

It follows simple_form semantics nicely and also eliminates the need to remember to pass `type` option.

**Explanation**

By the time you are passing `wrapper: :mine_special` option in the template, simple form initializers code has already been run, so you cannot simply insert an if statement in wrappers block. When you call the wrapper from template, it merges your options with the ones you defined in initializers.

I can imagine a way to override some methods in [SimpleForm::FormBuilder](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/ac63da0f0b38df82385493f25f649e320b0acb4a/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb) to route your wrapper calls based on `type` option you pass in, but at that time I'll probably be wondering if it's worth the complexity.